# DDD bounded context как правильно соединять сущности и базу

Tags: php, laravel, ddd

Всем привет, начал смотреть в сторону DDD и не совсем понятен вот такой момент, есть допустим контекст (микросервис) **продукты**, а также **категории** и **пользователи**.
При выборке продуктов/продукта должен выбираться пользователь и категории в которой есть продукт, у пользователя должны выбираться продукты, а у категории продукты которые есть в этой категории.
Сам вопрос, если идти правильно но **User**, **Product** и **Categories** это три разных контекста (микросервиса) но как мне тогда делать sql по выборке продуктов если контекст Product не должен знать о контексте **Пользователя** и **Категорий** и на оборот?

**P.S.** Слово "микросервис" я указал специально, потому что микросервисы обычно как я понимаю находятся на разных машинах (в большинстве случаев) и он должен быть изолирован он других сервисов, но как тогда обходить кейсы когда нужно в sql запросах делать join

Comment: Что-то мне кажется вы путаете понятие сущности и контекста....... такое ощущение, что у вас именно сущеости впихнуты в микросервисы.....Каждая сущность в приложении, например `User`, может быть в нескольких контекстах. И при таком подходе мне кажется нет проблем как обращаться к связанным данным, т.к. они находятся в одном контексте и одном сервисе.......Это как вижу я

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня нет микросервисов, я их привел для понимания что я хочу понять, я вроде понимаю что такое сущность, это сам User, а вот контекст это то где находится это User, верно?  Просто если User будет находится в нескольких контекстах, а как быть если один и тот-же код нужен будет в разных контекстах, получается мне придется дублировать код?

Comment: "*придется дублировать код?*" --- Да. Здесь про DRY придётся забыть. Точнее DRY это так или иначе не совсем про "всё что повторяется - выносить куда-либо" он чуть о другом....но да... при DDD и связанных контекстах бывает так, что что-то дублируется...... во всяком случае сущность с некоторыми данными точно.....зато именно такой подход даёт независимость от других контекстов и пр.. уменьшает "связанность"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я про дублирование не только сущностей, а про целые куски кода допустим запросов, каких-то логик к примеру построения структуры дерева категорий, потому так или иначе оно может понадобится и в контексте продуктов и в контексте категорий, это тоже получается нормальным? Просто всегда пытался все что только возможно переписать, а тут прям целые классы с огромной логикой могут повторятся…

Comment: "*допустим запросов, каких-то логик к примеру построения структуры дерева категорий*" --- построение дерева ни к какому контексту не принадлежит....и даже ни к какой сущности....дерево строить можно вообще не привязываясь ни к чему. Это может быть утилитарная сущность. В контекст она может быть разве что дополнена индивидуальными параметрами или логикой, если таковая понадобится вообще..... Это как класс "Вывод"... он общий, а вот вывести в консоль и вывести в файл на диске - это уже вещи основанные на общем классе.

Comment: Так что тут надо много смотреть. Конкретного точного ответа что "надо делать так и точка" тут нет.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если это не должно быть в контексте, тогда где?

Comment: Какой-то общей папке очевидно  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯